# Java - replace string between spaces using regex

Tags: java, regex

Example:

```
Word word hfjfbbcbcTomdhdh word
```

How do I replace the whole word in the middle between the spaces knowing only that it has the string Tom inside?

Output should be:

```
word word word word
```

How am I doing that? When i'm trying to, it goes to first and last spaces.

Comment: You have to write your own program using your own brains

Comment: lot of same kinda questions are already on SO

Comment: Have my own program, 7300 lines. Im just trying to do it but no success. It goes to the first and last spaces..

Comment: Would you please help me understanding how its done?

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://regexone.com/ as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476714/is-there-a-good-online-interactive-regex-tutorial

Comment: Please be more clear. Show your input, the unwanted output you are getting, the expected output and your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple regex:

```
    String input = "Word word hfjfbbcbcTomdhdh word more words withTomInIt and againTom";
    System.out.println(input.replaceAll("\\b\\S*Tom\\S*\\b", "FOO"));

=> "Word word FOO word more words FOO and FOO"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use String utility, like replace or sub string.